# Templatization for different countries

Tags: 7

Which is the best module to do a multilingual site for different countries. This is the exact word from client requirement.

"Site created for ABC country can be quickly adapted for country XYZ"

They are mainly looking for reuse of code.  Like they create a website for one country and they reuse the same code and same DB fro different county but language will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal has user interface localisation out of the box.  For user generated content,  [I18N module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) will be your friend.  This module offers an interface for translation and contains submodules to translate your menus, paths, variables, including your node content.  You can even [hook-up to IcanLocalize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/howto-translate-drupal-sites/) and have your content translated by professional translators.

Be aware, with all this power comes a small cost: there is some tweaking and configuring to do before everything plays nice, first time *can* be painful. I *very* highly recommend you [read the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/133977) before diving in, to have an idea of how the pieces work together.

Good-luck, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try something like this:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
    $language = $vars['language']->language;
    $vars['template_file'] = 'page-'. $language;
}
```